# Chart JS no animation line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm struggling against ChartJS.
I have to update my datas sometime so I use the method `update()` like said in the doc.

But when I update my chart, I don't have the animation.
I'm using **Firefox 60.1** on **Linux**, maybe this can cause the problem but I don't think cause when I go on the official chartjs site I can see everything and working well.

This [Fiddle-pie](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lda1ow2/73/) works well I have an animation and this [Fiddle-Line](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lda1ow2/72/) doesn't work : No animation.

Is there a difference in use of those 2 graphs ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated a js fiddle link of your issue here
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshmandiwal/rofyw2b3/1/)  your just add `backgroundColor: ["rgb(40, 37, 89)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(8, 197, 94)", "rgb(255, 99, 132)"],` in your code

Comment: Thank you but actually I'm using a palette color scheme but I didnt want to include it to th js fiddle.